# Requiring fields depending on address type

Tags: sylius

In our project we need to add custom fields to the addresses. That's already done extending Adress Model, but now we need that some fields will be required or not required depending on address type.

For example, field_1 must be filled for shipping address 
field_2 must be filled for billing address

field_2 is optional for shipping
field_1 is optional for billing

How could we accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little tricky but not so hard. You need to use Validation groups from symfony for your model. For every group you will define rules and then validate with group. You can apply group in any step, even after submbit. PLease see few links

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html#validation-groups

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Comment: Thanks!. Exactly how i did it. Just wondering if sylius had any other own config to do this (like a field in.the entity saying if address is shipping or billing), i saw taht the provide form already did some things depending on address type. Knowing this, i added a 'billable' group from a form extension.

Comment: @user1643155 you can override groups in sylius, but still need to do symfony way. Be aware if you dont have group that Symfony uses "Default" as group and validation cannot be overriden they are merged